# package helm chart referencing extra config file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart i need to package using the command `helm package` https://helm.sh/docs/helm/#helm-package but issue is i need to replace values.yaml file with extra config file depending on what environment

normally i reference this extra config file with

> **for QA**

```
helm install -f myvalues-qa.yaml -f override-qa.yaml --set foo=bar-qa --set foo=newbar-qa ./redis
```

> **for PROD**

```
helm install -f myvalues-prod.yaml -f override-prod.yaml --set foo=bar-prod --set foo=newbar-prod ./redis
```

but now since i want to package this redis helm charts, how do i package it so that i can switch which config files or extra vars depending the environment?

Here is what i tried

```
helm package -f myvalues-qa.yaml ./redis
```

> Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f .

What is best way to approach this?

Comment: why not keep all values files in chart? I see nothing bad with it.

Comment: because values are different for different environment..QA is not same as PROD for example

Answer (score 2):

When packaging a Helm chart it isn't possible to customize values. That's because of a helm chart is a generic definition of an app, reusable for one environment to another, which is customized at installing via values.

Apart from that, I understand that you need a way to store the definition of a release (including the helm chart and the values) for every specific environment. There are plenty of tools that let you define a release in a declarative way, here are some:

- [Helmfile](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile)
- [Landscaper](https://github.com/Eneco/landscaper/)
- [Reckoner](https://github.com/reactiveops/reckoner)

So, you have a packaged chart where you store the generic app and another file(s) where you store the definitions of the releases of this chart.

Comment: `"...which is customized at installing via values..."` is there a way to customize it with values by referencing a yaml file with multiple values? it can get too ugly when one need to modify like 20 values..which is why there is need for the extra file to modify multiple values